# How to disable "Read more" link in product description? (ubercart, drupal6)

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

I want to make all product description on the product page visible, I don't need "Read more" link at all.
How I can configure this? "Length of trimmed posts" in admin/content/node-settings is Unlimited.

Comment: You can accomplish this by [views](http://drupal.org/project/views). I think you already using views to make product page. Currently you are having teaser mode display, so you are getting "read more". you can change it to "show fields" and can display whatever you want.

Comment: Hm.. I don't have such View, only uc_products for the products list.

Comment: can you tell me the path (not site url, just drupal menu) on which you are listing products.

Comment: I have installed a fresh ubercart, and didn't see any product listing for anon user. rather that admin/store/products. So I think I can simply create a view and display all products. I didn't install any ohter module, just drupal.org/project/ubercart